# Java DAO Generics

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, generics, dao

I am using generics to build a DAO. The database could be any database. The problem is that for each type of class there is a specific class. For example:

```
public class DAO<T> {

    public void save(T entity) {

     }
}

public class StudentDAO extends DAO<Student> {

}
```

Just imagine I have 1000 tables or more. Do I need to have 1000 classes like this? Is there a better way to design this?

Edit

I am using MongoDB a NoSQL database with Spring MongoDB. It has Repository concept through Spring but I will still end up with 1000 classes. I cannot use JPA or Hibernate. Any other solution?

Comment: 1000+ tables with different table structures? Sorry, but I would reconsider my database design.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. But I'd recommend you to use [Generic Dao](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) project. It supports both native Hibernate and JPA API and allows you to create one and only one DAO for all entities you have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to extend DAO class. I assume DAO constructor has a parameter to detect which entity and which table it should interact with. Something like this:

```
public DAO(Class<T> type) {
    this.persistentType = type;
}
```

With such constructor, wherever you need a DAO instance for Student entity you can initialize it like this:

```
DAO<Student> studentDao = new DAO<Student>(Student.class);
```

Comment: Why would you want to add a constructor parameter when you can get the necessary information from your generic type?

Comment: @KurtDuBois How can we get the necessary information from just a generic?

Comment: Code example:   AbstractDao<T> dao = (AbstractDao<T>) this;
  ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) dao
    .getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
  this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass
    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];

Comment: Thanks Kurt, but sounds like it works only if a AbstractDao class is explicitly extended which is not desirable in this case.If no subclass extend AbstractDao, type "T" cannot be determined programatically at Runtime.
The method you mentioned is used in [GenericDataAccessObjects](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects). Note that it's an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is definitely a better way. What you bumped into is what I call the "DAO-per-entity scalability issue". What you need for that is a **reusable Generic DAO** implementation e.g. [PerfectJPattern](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/dp-genericdao.html)

```
 IGenericDao<Long, Customer> myCustomerDao = HibernateDaoFactory.getInstance().createDao(Customer.class);
 // create a Customer
 Customer myCustomer1 = new Customer(/*name=*/"Pedro"); 
 myCustomerDao.create(myCustomer1);
 // find all customers whose name is "Juan"
 List<Customer> myMatches = myCustomerDao.findByExample(new Customer(/*name=*/"Juan"));
```

what just happened here? you don't need to create a new `CustomerDao` but **reuse the generic one**. In addition to the basic CRUD, you may even cover 90% of your "finder" needs using the `findByExample` see [IGenericReadOnlyDao](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/perfectjpattern/jee/api/integration/dao/IGenericReadOnlyDao.html#findByExample%28Element,%20java.lang.String...%29).

If the `findByExample` does not cover all your needs then you have the choice to use the Spring level Generic DAO, [example here](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/xref/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/spring/Example.html) that offers direct mapping from SQL to your DAO interface and you don't need to provide an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Spring Data , which will generate DAO layer for you.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. The problem is that I am using a NoSQL database called MongoDB with Spring MongoDB. Spring Data has repositories but has the same problem has described above. By using Repository through Spring I will still end up with 1000 classes. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You consider use hibernate + spring